# maxLenght on TextField or RichTextField

Tags: admin-on-rest

I want to display only a small part of the description/message in the LIST view and show the whole message only in the SHOW view.

I know it has the option `secondaryTextLines={2}` for the small Responsive style, but couldn't find the way to do this in the `< Datagrid ... />`.

I've tried adding the option `options={{ multiLine: true, maxLenght: "2" }}` and similar variations, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That's what we do in the demo for review comments:

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest-demo/#/reviews

Code for the comment field is here:
https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/master/src/reviews/index.js#L56

In a nutshell:

```
<TextField
    source="comment"
    style={{
        maxWidth: '18em',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    }}
/>
```